# google analytics tracking on iframe

Tags: google-analytics

How to track urls in iframes with Google Analytics?

What I do is that I put this code inside the iframe, like I do on the "top" window.. But the iframe isn't tracked in analytics?

This should work, but it doesn't.. :(

## iframe

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var _gaq = _gaq || [];
            _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-35706930-1']);
            _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);
            
            (function() {
                var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
                ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
                var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
            })();
        </script>
    </head>
    
    <body></body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

at face value, there's no reason it shouldn't work. But GA will track based on the iframe URL, not the parent URL, so if the iframe is hosted on some other domain, you may have problems, depending on your settings within GA.  Check to make sure you are using the right account #.  Check to make sure you don't have any profile filters (such as an 'include only xyx.com' domain) or anything else in your settings that exclude domains, etc..

Also note that if the iframe is on a different domain, you're going to run into issues with tracking in general as far as session and visit(or) metrics.  In order to get around this, you will need to implement additional [cross-domain tracking](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite). Not having this would not cause NO data to show up, so this in and of itself isn't the root issue.

Comment: @Clark Did you solve with cross-domain tracking? May you explain the solution better?

Comment: Your link is out dated. please use this one : https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1034342?hl=en#zippy=%2Cin-this-article

Comment: my gtag.js in iframe doesn't call the collection point `www.google-analytics.com/g/collect` if the iframe is inside a chrome extension