# Google analytics iframe tracking

Tags: iframe, analytics, tracking

I'm looking to track iframe and the content/destination url in the iframe. But the requirement is **GA Event tracking generated from iframe inherits the page level dimensions &metrics set by page view** and looking to pass same cookie value from parent iframe. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: possible duplicate of [google analytics tracking on iframe](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14459675/google-analytics-tracking-on-iframe)

Comment: I tried with that option..but nothing is working for me. I want to track iframe content and events in iframe for child page also like parent page. Can anyone help on this please.